# Duda en cuanto a definir una funcion en Haskell

Tags: haskell

tengo problemas para implementar una función en haskell de la siguiente manera:

De una lista de triplas xs, necesito los números pares de la misma, eliminando el primer valor de cada tripla.
Por ejemplo:

```
Solo2y3 :: [(a,b,c)] -> [(b,c)]
```

De otra forma:

```
Solo2y3 [(1,2,True),(2,5,False)]= [(2,True),(5,False)]
```

Si alguien podría darme una ayuda, lo agradezco mucho.

Comment: No parece un problema complicado. ¿Has intentado algo que no te ha salido?

Answer (score 0):

```
solo2y3 :: [(a,b,c)] -> [(b,c)]
solo2y3 = map (\(_,y,z) -> (y,z))
```

No puedes nombrar una función con mayúscula inicial en Haskell